# Prolog: Inverse Predicate for all Bindings

Tags: prolog

If I have some facts about how much money people own

```
% poor people
owns(luke,1).
owns(maria,3).
owns(sara,5).
owns(mike,9).

% rich people
owns(barbara,10).
owns(paula,11).
owns(thierry,19).
```

and a predicate `isRich` (returns true if a person P owns 10 or more)

```
isRich(P) :-
    owns(P,M),
    M >= 10.
```

I can call `isRich(X)` and I will get all bindings for X where X is a rich person, i.e.

```
?- isRich(X).
X = barbara ;
X = paula ;
X = thierry.
```

Now I want to have a predicate `isPoor` which is the inverse of `isRich`, i.e. it returns all bindings for poor people (people who own less than 10). Of course, I could write:

```
isPoor(P) :-
    owns(P,M),
    M < 10.
```

**However**, I want to write `isPoor` by calling `isRich`. Thus, when I change the predicate `isRich` (assume `isRich` is a more complex predicate) I don't have to change `isPoor`. Ideally, I would want to write something like:

```
isPoor(P) :-
    not(isRich(P)).
```

But when I call `isPoor(X)` as is defined above, I just get false instead of getting all possible bindings for X where X is a poor person:

```
?- isPoor(X).
false.
```

What I want is:

```
?- isPoor(X).
X = luke ;
X = maria ;
X = sara ;
X = mike.
```

Is there a way in SWI Prolog to call the inverse of a predicate such that it binds all possible variables?

Comment: You can enumerate the ppl and then call `isRich/1` as in `isPoor(P) :- owns(P,_), \+ isRich(P).`

Comment: Thank you, @TomasBy! I posted your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Thomas By [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49600065/prolog-inverse-predicate-for-all-bindings/49607904#comment86207430_49600065), this does the trick:

```
% enumerate all people and
% return the ones that aren't rich
isPoor(P) :-
    owns(P,_),
    \+ isRich(P).
```